# How to give a Firebase editor the ability to read/write Firestore database in Firebase console?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

We hired a dev, we made him an editor on Firebase, he needs to read/write Firestore from within the console. He can't do that as an editor, this issue didn't happen before but suddenly all of the editors stopped having permission to see Firestore.

How to fix that permissions issue?

Comment: As an editor on the project the user should be able to make changes to Firestore. If that is not happening for you (anymore), [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/wmvcov/how_to_give_a_firebase_editor_the_ability_to/